# How to become Moderator in Cardano Stack Exchange Network?

Tags: discussion, moderation

I see a lot of users are automatically chnaged from normal user into Moderator So is their steps to follow to be Moderator or specific number of reputation or badge or something other.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Those users are "community managers", and they are employees (working full-time and getting paid a salary) from the Stack Exchange company.

To become a "site moderator", there will be 3 candidates chosen via an ***election*** which will take place at least a month from now (if and only if the site passes the Private Beta stage and enters Public Beta).

Comment: How to apply for Community Manager?

Comment: It's rare that new CMs are recruited. They hired at least three new CMs very recently, so I don't know if they'll be hiring more in the near-future. Catija might be able to tell you if there's any likelihood for more CM recruitment in the near-future.

Comment: We are, in fact, *currently* hiring CMs but it's a role that requires either CM experience elsewhere or moderation experience here on SE. https://stackoverflow.com/company/work-here/3049910/community-manager-curator-support-team